Unable to deploy lambda script with webpack in Serverless architecture AWS
I am very new to learning Serverless and nod.js. I am trying to deploy a lambda script by compressing with webpack but getting following error:

No matching handler found for 'lambdas/getProperties' in '/Users/pankajsachdeva/Desktop/HD/work/Practice/AWS/airbnb-clone'. Check your service definition.

serverless.yml:
    plugins:
  - serverless-s3-sync
  - serverless-webpack  

package:
  individually: true

custom:
  s3Sync:
    - bucketName: serverless-airbnb-clone-20240413
      localDir: UploadData
  webpackIncludeModules: true

functions:
  getProperties:
    handler: lambdas/getProperties.handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: get-properties/{ID}
          method: GET
          cors: true

resources:
  Resources:
    AirBnBCloneUpload:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        BucketName: serverless-airbnb-clone-20240413

lambdas/getProperties:
const Responses = require('./API_Responses')

exports.handler = async event => {

    if (!event.pathParameters || !event.pathParameters.ID) {
        // failed without an ID
        return Responses._400({message: 'missing the ID from the path'})
    }

    let ID = event.pathParameters.ID;

    if(data[ID]){
        //return data
        return Responses._200(data[ID]);
    }
    return Responses._400({ message: 'no ID in data' });
}

const data =  {
    1234: { name: 'Anna Jones', age: 25, job: 'journalist' },
    4567: { name: 'Chris Martin', age: 42, job: 'doctor' },
    8901: { name: 'Tom Hogue', age: 31, job: 'teacher' },
    2345: { name: 'Garry Smith', age: 52, job: 'programmer' }
};

I am getting this error after using webpack. It is working fine when I remove webpack. So I am sure that path is correct and there is some problem with webpack config in serverless.yml.
Edit:
web.config.js:
module.exports = {
    target: 'node',
    mode: 'production',
};


Need more info regarding your webpack build. How is the entry defined and the output? This is most likely related to an additional name being included during the build which is interfering with how the lambda runtime expects to find your handler.

Why do you use webpack at all? If you think you need it try rollup.

TBH I don't know(please check my first 7 words of the Post), I am following a tutorial on youtube, as per him if I use webpack I will have my file as reduced size and only as my coding file. I thought it should be good to have file with less size. I am not sure about rollup, will check it now
